# jQuery - Parsing JSON inside script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I tried to parse JSON string inside a script tag `<script src='//remotehost/test.js'>{'1':'2'}</script>`

```
dom = document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1]; //it gets the correct tag, checked
d = $.parseJSON($(dom).html());
```

But I get `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data` error. I checked http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/ and the result of `$(dom).html()` is listed as one of malformatted JSON string result. How do I parse the JSON using jQuery?

Comment: Why do you have both an `src` and text inside a script element?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy text inside script act as flexible data to the script.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that it's not valid JSON.  Valid JSON uses double quotes.

Change your HTML to:

```
<script src='//remotehost/test.js'>{"1":"2"}</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`{'1':'2'}` is a JavaScript Object, not a correct JSON.

JSON format of Object is a String use Double quotation marks, like: `'{"1": "2"}'`